# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/util/function/SerializableFunction

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql, flink-batch

flink version:1.14.2
hive version:2.1.1
use flink connect hive exec batch process,happend err.

use flink sql exec query
java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

```java
java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/util/function/SerializableFunction
        at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.table.JdbcOutputFormatBuilder.build(JdbcOutputFormatBuilder.java:100)
        at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.table.JdbcDynamicTableSink.getSinkRuntimeProvider(JdbcDynamicTableSink.java:89)
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.common.CommonExecSink.createSinkTransformation(CommonExecSink.java:121)
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.batch.BatchExecSink.translateToPlanInternal(BatchExecSink.java:59)
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.ExecNodeBase.translateToPlan(ExecNodeBase.java:134)
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.BatchPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(BatchPlanner.scala:82)
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.BatchPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(BatchPlanner.scala:81)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.BatchPlanner.translateToPlan(BatchPlanner.scala:81)
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.PlannerBase.translate(PlannerBase.scala:185)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.translate(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:1665)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:752)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:872)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeSql(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:742)
        at com.zhhainiao.wp.stat.PaidConversationRate$.main(PaidConversationRate.scala:172)
        at com.zhhainiao.wp.stat.PaidConversationRate.main(PaidConversationRate.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222)
        at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:114)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:812)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:246)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1054)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1132)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1132)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/util/function/SerializableFunction
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the correct Hive dependencies, as explained on https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/connectors/table/hive/overview/#dependencies ?